# Show Code Assist

Tags: code

I want to cancel the Auto Popup in the options menu. It turns to False but when I come back to the code it turns to true again. I clicked in Apply. I need to turn it off because it sometimes does not work and got stuck says "not respond" and closes the program.
Do you have any idea why it does not turn it off?

Thanks